# How can I tell why 20.04 is crashing?

Tags: 20.04, crash

For the past week or so, Ubuntu 20.04 randomly freezes (3 or 4 times a day) on my Dell XPS Developer Edition laptop.  All I can do is hold down the power button to manually turn off the machine and then restart.

There are no logs in `/var/crash` and running

```
journalctl -b -1 -e
```

doesn't reveal any logged info - the last logged item is about 10 minutes before the crash.

I also installed sensors and was monitoring the temp yesterday while working.  When a crash happened the temperature was normal (about 40.0°C on all cores).

All software is up to date.

Each time it crashes I'm doing something different.  The only common program I (probably?) have open is Chrome though I'm not completely sure, it's just a guess because I almost always have it open.

Any help is appreciated.  18.04 rarely crashed and 20.04 was fine at first but several months after upgrading here I am...

It's a Dell XPS 13 7390
Intel® Core™ i7-10710U CPU @ 1.10GHz × 12

---

```
aaron@xps13:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       1.7Gi        11Gi       640Mi       2.3Gi        12Gi
Swap:          31Gi          0B        31Gi
```

---

```
aaron@xps13:~$ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
```

---

```
aaron@xps13:~$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
[sudo] password for aaron: 
1.5.1
```

---

```
aaron@xps13:~$ grep -i swap /etc/fstab
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

---

```
aaron@xps13:~$ ls -al /var/crash
total 8
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4096 Jun 29 07:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root     4096 Apr 18 21:51 ..
```

---

```
aaron@xps13:~$ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
ls: cannot access '/home/aaron/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file or directory
aaron@xps13:~$ ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jun  2 11:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Jul  9 23:04 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 11 14:33 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun  2 11:48 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 18 22:38 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

Disks screenshot

[image]

[`grep -i ata /var/log/syslog*`](https://pastebin.com/j80metfn)

[`grep -i iwlwifi /var/log/syslog*`](https://pastebin.com/kYnP09TJ)

[`/var/log/syslog` showing crash](https://pastebin.com/D0upvqwM)

```
aaron@xps13:~$ uname -r
5.4.0-40-generic
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110632/discussion-on-question-by-aaron-how-can-i-tell-why-20-04-is-crashing).

Answer (score 5):

Dell XPS 13 7390

**BIOS**

Your BIOS is current at version 1.5.1.

**fsck**

You have a dirty file system.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**memtest**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**swap**

Your /swapfile is excessive. There's no guarantee that this will fix your problem, but it might. We'll reduce /swapfile from 31G to 4G.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 16G RAM and 4G swap
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

Add this line to /etc/fstab (if it doesn't already exist)...

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

**Samsung NVMe**

Check for firmware updates for your Samsung NVMe. Download the `Samsung Magician` [here](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/). This will require Windows, or you can try building a FreeDOS USB stick to do this.

Comment: Thank you!  I've followed the commands to lower the swap.  It will be a few days before I can boot from an external drive and clean up the file system.  Not sure about checking firmware for the SSD with Windows... but I will attempt it if all else fails.

Comment: @Aaron Please do keep me posted. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Aaron Status please...

Comment: I posted an update in the chat.  Since then I reinstalled 20.04 a few days ago and so far no crashes.  Still no clue why they happened or if another will happen at any time...

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for the update. Did you ever run `memtest`?

Comment: Yes, took a while to complete but passed 4/4.

Comment: @Aaron Good. You might search here on AU for "Dell XPS 13", as there seem to be a lot of noise about this model, and it may require a special kernel parameter at boot time to fix this problem.

Comment: thanks, I will.  And really, thank you very much for helping me so thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar crashes and figured out the problem was my Nvidia GPU. Nvidia drivers are are not compatible on Ubuntu. I switched to my Intel GPU and crashes are gone. For Ubuntu just use AMD or Intel. Problem is AMD are all power hogs and will wreck a regular office machine that does not have 500 PSU or greater. I don't do gaming so  I don't even need a great GPU. Just no more crashing is all I care about now. Lesson learned. Make sure you only buy a computer that can support the non-Nvidia GPU of your choice. That means find out how much power your GPU REALLY will require, not what the manufacturer claims.