# Ubuntu 20.04 system freezes [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, xorg, intel-graphics

My Ubuntu 20.04 system has been affected by occasional freezes (~ each 1-2 days) which completely blocks any interaction (not even REISUB works) and requires pressing on the power button to restart the computer. This is a brand new installation on a laptop MSI GF65 Thin 10SER. I have done some research already and this seems to be an old problem (https://linuxreviews.org/Linux_Kernel_5.5_Will_Not_Fix_The_Frequent_Intel_GPU_Hangs_In_Recent_Kernels, https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/intel-microcode-atomic-update.html, https://hobo.house/2018/05/18/fix-for-intel-i915-gpu-freeze-on-recent-linux-kernels/) related to the Intel iGPU.

My `dmesg` is full of lines such as the ones below and **inevitably they cause the system to freeze**.

```
[drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=9338 end=9339) time 321 us, min 1063, max 1079, scanline start 1038, end 1090
```

`$ uname -r`

```
5.4.0-58-generic
```

`$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 05)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 12aa
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 12aa
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

**I have tried the following:**

- Add the kernel options `i915.enable_psr=0`, `i915.enable_dc=0`
- Enable early KMS for the Intel graphics driver (add i915 to /etc/initramfs-tools/modules)
- Enable GuC with `i915.enable_guc=2`, however it isn't working as  `$ sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/i915_guc_load_status | grep status:` returns `status: DISABLED`
- Change the X.Org display driver to modeset instead of the xserver-xorg-video-intel
- Update the linux kernel to 5.8
- Add the following to /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-intel.conf

  ```
    Section "Device"
      Identifier "Intel Graphics"
      Driver "intel"
      Option "NoAccel" "True"
      Option "DRI" "False"
    EndSection
  ```

One observation is that when I change the Prime Profile to Performance mode (i.e. only the nvidia gpu is used and the intel one isn't) I don't get any of these errors in dmesg. However this isn't a solution for me since this options drains my battery very quickly.

I am a new Ubuntu user and I would really appreciate if someone could give a hand or just provide a workaround so I can have a stable system with no crashes. Let me know if you need any additional information. Thanks in advance!

### Update 20/12/2020:

Setting `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0"` on /etc/default/grub stopped the `dmesg` atomic update failure errors. However, now `glxinfo|egrep "OpenGL renderer"` gives `OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 256 bits)` instead of `OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics (CML GT2)`. This is a problem because now I get extremely high CPU usage from `gnome-shell`. I don't really know what to take out from this information.

Help would be much appreciated.

In the meanwhile I have restored the grub configuration and done some other changes.
`$ inxi -G`

```
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Device-2: NVIDIA TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060] driver: nvidia v: 450.80.02 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: modesetting,nvidia 
           resolution: 1920x1080~144Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (CML GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.8
```

### Update 21/12/2020:

Ok so I have been running my system with the Nvidia Prime performance profile on (I think this means the iGPU isn't being used, only the dGPU - nvidia - is) and I just got a freeze while listening to Spotify (which happens to also be one of the reasons why my computer has frozen in the past), however this time I didn't register any Atomic update error in this session and `journalctl -b -1 -e` didn't register anything relevant (at least for me). I will follow the answer to this question [How can I tell why 20.04 is crashing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258529/how-can-i-tell-why-20-04-is-crashing) and then I will update the topic. Let me know if there's any output/ information you need to understand better the problem.

### Update 23/12/2020:

I performed a memtest from https://www.memtest86.com/ and got 0 errors (results below):
[image: MemTest86 results]

I also did a clean install of Ubuntu, Mint and Manjaro. Every one of them would show the Atomic update error in `dmesg`. I sent the laptop for the repair service as I think the problem is due to hardware malfunction.

---

So the laptop came out from RMA and they told me there was nothing wrong with it. Unfortunately I had to switch to Windows as I can't afford having an unstable system like I described above. In the future I may try to install a newer version of Ubuntu to check if the problem persists.

Comment: Are you using GNOME or GNOME on Xorg? The same issue happened to me on Wayland.

Comment: Hi @QA1. I am using GNOME on Xorg. `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` gives me `x11`.

Comment: Followed [link](https://medium.com/@carlosero/making-ubuntu-18-04-work-on-msi-gs65-8re-9818f4d9dc9d) and added `nouveau.blacklist=1 nouveau.modeset=0` to /etc/default/grub on the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX line. It seems to have improved the situation quite a lot. I will let you know if I continue having freezes but the system looks quite stable now.

Answer (score 0):

I have been stalking this thread because I have a similar issue on a ~6 year old card after switching to Arch last december and hoped to find a clue here.

In the meantime I tried the suggestions in this thread (except I have no GuC support) as well as from other places, including setting

`i915.enable_psr=0`
among other things but no change!

Finally read on reddit about setting

`intel_idle.max_cstate=1`
in

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`
and had no freeze in a whole week of uptime with regular use!

for more info visit https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=263884